How to handle Authentication and private routes in React-native + Node.js?
I want a good way to handle Authentication in React-Native. I was planning on using JWT tokens and make the accessToken refresh without making the user ever log-in again(assuming they have a refreshToken).
But I have to query my backend and pass it my tokens at the entry of each page to see if the token is valid. So I have a bunch of repeated code across my components. Is there a better way of handling this?
I don't have to use JWT tokens, if there is a better way. I'm unsure if I need to check if the user is valid at each page, or I can just not use JWT tokens and assume if they're on that page they are valid?
I suppose in summary my question is: How can I ensure a user only reaches certain pages when they're properly authenticated, and not make them sign in each time?
//Verify Token component:
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";

export default function VerifyToken({ navigation }: { navigation: any }) {
    async function getToken(key: string) {
        let result = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
        if (result) {
            return result;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    async function save(key: string, value: string) {
        await SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value);
    }

    async function verifyToken() {
        let accessToken;
        let refreshToken;

        accessToken = await getToken("accessToken");
        refreshToken = await getToken("refreshToken");

        if (!accessToken || !refreshToken) {
            navigation.navigate("Login");
            return;
        }

        try {
            let response = await fetch("http://10.0.2.2:8000/auth/validToken", {
                //this one works
                //http://localhost:8000/test
                //Setting Method
                method: "GET",
                headers: { accessToken: accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken },
            });
            if (response) {
                let data = await response.json();
                console.log(data);
                await save("accessToken", data.accessToken);
                await save("refreshToken", data.refreshToken);
                return;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Something went wrong");
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        verifyToken();
    }, []);
}

//Any Other page:
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import VerifyToken from "./VerifyToken"; // Adjust the path as necessary

export default function Home({ navigation }: { navigation: any }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        VerifyToken(navigation);
    }, []);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.heading}>Home Page. Should only be here if user is valid</Text>
        </View>
    );
}


In React I usually store my JWT tokens in cookies and have a privateRoutes.js file to do a verify token check on each protected page. But I don't believe I have such an option in React-Native
